# Vimeo API - Get categories and credits

Tags: api, categories, vimeo, vimeo-api, credits

I'm doing a script that takes a video ID from Vimeo, calls the API and populate the database with all the data we need.

I'm able to get all the fields and everything is working well using that url:
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}

I can also use the query ?fields=name, etc... To only get the fields i need.

But when i make that request to the API (even when i use the fields query), the categories array is empty and the credits are returned as this:

```
"credits": {
    "uri": "/videos/{video_id}/credits",
    "options": [
        "GET",
        "POST"
    ],
    "total": 1
}
```

If i make another request, to those url:
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}/credits 
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}/categories

I get all the info i need about the credits and categories.

The problem is: i do not want to make 3 request to the API to get everything i need. Why are the credits and categories not included in the original video request?
Is there a way i can do it with one call?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding categories, the video may not be categorized, either by the video owner or a Vimeo Curator. When a video has not been categorized, the categories array will return empty.

For example, this test video returns no categories:

```
curl -X GET 
  'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/76979871?fields=uri,categories' 
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

While this Staff Picked video returns several categories and subcategories:

```
curl -X GET 
  'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/274849065?fields=uri,categories.uri,categories.uri,categories.name,categories.top_level' 
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

Regarding credits, a video will always have a minimum of one credit (the video owner). I suggest adding some logic so that if metadata.connections.credits.total is greater than 1, then make the additional request to get those other credited users.

For instance, this same Staff Picked video returns metadata.connections.credits.total=2, so to get the additional credited user, you'll need to make a request to the video's credits endpoint.

```
curl -X GET 
  'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/274849065?fields=uri,metadata.connections.credits' 
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

The reason for the separate endpoint for credits is that each user object can contain a lot of metadata -- if a video credits many users, the video response (which is already quite large) can be even bigger if the fields parameter isn't used.

I hope this information helps!

Comment: Thank you for your time!
Actually, like i said, the video has categories and i'm able to access them using https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}/categories.
The original request just returns an empty array for some reason i ignore for now.

Also, you're right about the credits logic, i don't think i can do it without a second request, but the bare minimum like the name and the role would be useful to get inside the primary request.

Comment: @cryptomothy If a video has been categorized but isn't returning that metadata, it could be a bug with that specific video. I suggest reaching out to Vimeo and referencing this Stack Overflow thread: https://help.vimeo.com